# CSS offset-path move along arc without rotating

Tags: css, animation

I'm trying to create a circle button, with "flap" on side, when you click on the button, the flap should move alongside the circle to the bottom.

The flap gets to the bottom but it starts with rotating. How can I move it alongside the circle without the initial rotation?

Questions related to this code. Why isn't the flap clickable? Why is the cursor not a pointer even though it's set in css? How to make the animation reverse when it's not active?

Thank you

```js
$(".kolecko").on('click', function(){
$(this).toggleClass('active');
});
```

```css
.kolecko{
        width: 150px;
        height: 150px;
        border-radius: 50%;
        background: #001f49;
        color: white;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        flex-direction: column;
        text-align: center;
        position: relative;
        cursor: pointer;
        }
        .kolecko::after{
          font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
          font-weight: 900;
          content: "\f138";
          width: 40px;
          height: 50px;
          position: absolute;
          left: 100%;
          top: 50%;
          transform: translate(-4px,-50%);
          background: #8bc1ff;
          line-height: 50px;
          font-size: 25px;
          z-index: -1;
          border-top-right-radius: 10px;
          border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
          cursor:pointer;
        }
        
 .kolecko.active::after{
          content: "\f139";
          offset-path: path('M-75,-75 A75,75 -45 0,1 -75,75');
          animation: move 1000ms ease-in-out forwards;
        }
@keyframes move {
  0% {
    offset-distance: 50%;
  }
  100% {
    offset-distance: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.5.0/css/all.css" 
integrity="sha384- 
 B4dIYHKNBt8Bc12p+WXckhzcICo0wtJAoU8YZTY5qE0Id1GSseTk6S+L3BlXeVIU" 
  crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="kolecko" data-for="zalozit-klic">
                        <span class="chci">chci</span>
                        <span class="nazev-sluzby">ZALOŽIT s.r.o. NA KLÍČ</span>
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by replacing "after" with element with svg background. Added animation to swing back.

Using translate to flip the element and also tuck it under the main circle.
Inspiration on using translate by @laaouatni-anas

```js
 
 $(".kolecko").on('click', function (){
            const data = $(this).data('for');

            if($(this).hasClass('active')){
                $(this).removeClass('active');
                $('.kolecko').not(this).removeClass('non-active');
                $(this).addClass('wasActive')
                    .delay(1000)
                    .queue(function(next){
                        $(this).removeClass('wasActive');
                        next();
                    });
            }
            else if($(this).hasClass('non-active')){
                $('.kolecko').not(this)
                    .removeClass('active')
                    .addClass('non-active wasActive')
                    .delay(1000)
                    .queue(function(next){
                        $(this).removeClass('wasActive');
                        next();
                    });
                $(this).removeClass('non-active').addClass('active');

            }
            else{
                $('.kolecko').not(this).addClass('non-active');
                $(this).addClass('active');

             
            }

    });
```

```css
 .kolecko{
        width: 150px;
        height: 150px;
        border-radius: 50%;
        background: #001f49;
        color: white;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        flex-direction: column;
        text-align: center;
        position: relative;
        cursor: pointer;
 }
  .kolecko.active .ucho{
          background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 1175 1175'%3E%3Cpath style='fill:%23ed174a' class='fil0' d='M957 1l-957 -1c65,184 101,381 101,587 0,206 -36,404 -101,587l957 1c120,0 218,-98 218,-218l0 -738c0,-120 -98,-218 -218,-218z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
          offset-path: path('M-75,-75 A75,75 0 0,1 -75,75');
          animation: move 1000ms ease-in-out forwards;
          transform: rotate(-90deg) translate(calc(50% - 4px),0);
  }
.kolecko.active .ucho::after{
            content: "\f137";
          }

.kolecko.wasActive .ucho{
        offset-path: path('M-75,-75 A75,75 0 0,1 -75,75');
        animation: moveback 1000ms ease-in-out forwards;
        transform: rotate(-90deg) translate(calc(50% - 4px),0);
 }
.ucho{
          background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 1175 1175'%3E%3Cpath style='fill: %239BA1C6' class='fil0' d='M957 1l-957 -1c65,184 101,381 101,587 0,206 -36,404 -101,587l957 1c120,0 218,-98 218,-218l0 -738c0,-120 -98,-218 -218,-218z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
          background-repeat: no-repeat;
          width: 45px;
          height: 45px;
          background-size: 100% 100%;
          line-height: 45px;
          position: absolute;
          left: 100%;
          top: 50%;
          transform: translate(-4px,-50%);
          cursor: pointer;
}
.ucho::after{
            font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
            font-weight: 900;
            content: "\f138";
            font-size:25px;
}


@keyframes move {
  0% {
    offset-distance: 50%;
  }

  100% {
    offset-distance: 100%;
  }
}
@keyframes moveback {
  0% {
    offset-distance: 100%;
  }

  100% {
    offset-distance: 50%;

  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.5.0/css/all.css" 
integrity="sha384- 
 B4dIYHKNBt8Bc12p+WXckhzcICo0wtJAoU8YZTY5qE0Id1GSseTk6S+L3BlXeVIU" 
  crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="kolecko" data-for="zalozit-klic">
                        <span class="chci">chci</span>
                        <span class="nazev-sluzby">ZALOŽIT s.r.o. NA KLÍČ</span>
                        <span class="ucho">
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can specify [`offset-rotate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/offset-rotate) to restrict the rotation along the animation.

```css
offset-rotate: 0deg;
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I don't know how to solve this using `offset-path`... **but** I really want to help so...

*we can transform this BUG in a FEATURE :)*

so in your `@keyframe` at `100%` I added some `transform` properties... so the bug you can't see anymore!

**what I added:**

```css
transform: rotate(-90deg) translateX(40%);
```

**the complete `@keyframe` code:**

```css
@keyframes move {
    0% {
        offset-distance: 50%;
    }
    100% {
        offset-distance: 100%;
        transform: rotate(-90deg) translateX(40%);
    }
}
```

**complete fixed code snippet:**

```js
$(".kolecko").on('click', function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('active');
});
```

```css
.kolecko {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #001f49;
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.kolecko::after {
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
  font-weight: 900;
  content: "\f138";
  width: 40px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-4px, -50%);
  background: #8bc1ff;
  line-height: 50px;
  font-size: 25px;
  z-index: -1;
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.kolecko.active::after {
  content: "\f139";
  offset-path: path('M-75,-75 A75,75 -45 0,1 -75,75');
  animation: move 1000ms ease-in-out forwards;
}

@keyframes move {
  0% {
    offset-distance: 50%;
  }
  100% {
    offset-distance: 100%;
    transform: rotate(-90deg) translateX(40%);
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.5.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384- 
 B4dIYHKNBt8Bc12p+WXckhzcICo0wtJAoU8YZTY5qE0Id1GSseTk6S+L3BlXeVIU" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="./script.js" defer></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="kolecko" data-for="zalozit-klic">
    <span class="chci">chci</span>
    <span class="nazev-sluzby">ZALOŽIT s.r.o. NA KLÍČ</span>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for commenting, your solution helps the rotating part but not it doesn't look like it's following the circle, so it's little off as well. I don't insist on doing it by offset-path, even JS would be fine. Whatever has the best intended outcome. Do you have any other ideas how to do it? I would be very thankful.